# Confusion about precision

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

When I evaluate

```
x = 1.0000000000000000001 (* Precision of 20 digits *)
```

Mathematica returns

```
1.000000000000000000 (* Precision of 19 digits *)
```

When I evaluate

```
y = N[1.0000000000000000001,100]
```

it still returns

```
1.000000000000000000
```

despite the fact that we did know the original number with a precision of 20 digits so it seems it really does lose precision the moment it evaluates the number `1.0000000000000000001`. Trace also shows the calculation as if I just entered the number with a precision of 19 digits
When evaluate

```
SetPrecision[y,30]
```

it returns

```
1.00000000000000000010000000000
```

though...

I read through the documentation on arbitrary precision calculations and still don't get what's going on. If Mathematica stores the numbers internally with a higher precision then why doesn't N give me the result up to the highest precision the number has. If it doesn't store any precision then why does the missing digit suddenly appear when evaluating `SetPrecision`?

Comment: Note that `InputForm` and `RealDigits` both indicate that last digit is present. `In[14]:= InputForm[x = 1.0000000000000000001]
RealDigits[x]
Out[15]= {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 1}
1.0000000000000000001`19.`

Comment: See [`Numerical Precision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html#21155)

Answer (score 2):

```
1.0000000000000000001
1.000000000000000000
```

It's precision of display....

Have you learned C or C++? It's like:

```
printf("%.3d",1.000001);
```

If you mean:

```
1.0000000000000000001==1.0000000000000000000
```

It's because the default precision has only ten numbers, You need use`setPrecision` or like

```
1.0000000000000000001`22==1.0000000000000000000`22
```

There is refered in Possible Issues  (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)

It's mean `setPrecision[y,30]` make `Precision[y]` from 10 to 30... In other way, the infinite precision is you can set some value's precision infinite, not any of them is infinite defaultly.

(If you think my English is poor, it's because I'm not native English speaker....

Comment: But then why does ```Round[1.0000000000000000001] ==1.000000000000000001 ``` return ```True```?

Comment: @Gert why not? Round[1.0000000000000000001] ==1==1.000000000000000000

Comment: sorry, I copied the wrong number. Edited my comment.

Comment: Emm, I need to try it in my computer....

Comment: @Gert The "==" in documentation said, in my opinion, the default precision of value is  automatic precision ,it only care about the first ten numbers in 1.0000000000001,so....

Comment: @Gert you need use like ```1.0000000000000000001`22==1.0000000000000000000`22```

Comment: @Gert Is what you want to know? I mean do you understand? My English is poor... so if you are puzzled, please tell me....